# Figuring out the proof of limit

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble proving this limit as $n$ approaches infinity
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\,+\infty} \frac{1 + \cos n}{2 + \sqrt n}$$

It should be zero but I can't figure out the epsilon proof because I'm not sure if there's a way to isolate the $n$ without some sort of funky algebraic manipulation. Help please?

Comment: Is $n$ approaching $\infty$?

Comment: Oops. Left that out. Yeah as n approaches +infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Since $-1 \le \cos n \le 1$ for all $n$, we can estimate

$$\left|\frac{1 + \cos n}{2 + \sqrt n}\right| \le \frac{1 + |\cos n|}{2 + \sqrt n} \le \frac{2}{2 + \sqrt n}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ah I see. Is this sort of a general method to use when the algebraic process gets tricky? Compare it to something else we can figure it out for?

Comment: @rawrPanda Try to get rid of complicated terms, especially if they can be bounded in a useful way. This will help a lot with, for example, the sine and cosine functions.

Answer (score 1):

I find the left-hand part of the other answer unnecessary: (and actually I don't see how the answer actually answers the question but can't comment yet)

$$0 \le \frac{1 + \cos n}{2 + \sqrt n} \le \frac{2}{2 + \sqrt n}$$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem